# Error build skia: machine type x64 conflicts with x86

Tags: c++, windows, skia

I'm trying to build Skia as per the instructions here https://skia.org/docs/user/build/. I install the C++ clang tools for Windows using the Visual Studio Installer and then configured skia as follows:

> bin/gn gen out/Shared --args='clang_win="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm" is_component_build=true is_debug=false is_official_build=true skia_use_system_expat=false skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_system_libwebp=false skia_use_system_zlib=false skia_use_system_icu=false skia_use_system_harfbuzz=false target_cpu="x64"'

Then I ran `ninja -C out/Shared` but during the build process I get the following error:

```
FAILED: skia.dll skia.dll.lib skia.dll.pdb
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm/bin/lld-link.exe" /nologo /IMPLIB:./skia.dll.lib /DLL /OUT:./skia.dll /PDB:./skia.dll.pdb @./skia.dll.rsp
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(std_type_info_static.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(chkstk.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcpmt.lib(thread0.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcpmt.lib(xthrow.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(delete_scalar_size.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(new_scalar.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(utility.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcpmt.lib(locale.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcpmt.lib(iosptrs.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(guard_support.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcpmt.lib(syserror.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(gshandler.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(gshandlereh4.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(amdsecgs.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(gs_cookie.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(delete_scalar.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: libcmt.lib(cpu_disp.obj): machine type x64 conflicts with x86
lld-link: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use /errorlimit:0 to see all errors)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I'm running a 64bit version of Windows 11.
Anyone have any idea on what the issue might be?

Comment: The problem is mixing 32 bit and 64 bit between the libraries used and the code you are building. They both must match. I am not 100% sure which is 32 bit. I think the `libcmt.lib` is 32 bit and you are building for x64 so the path to the windows sdk libraries is wrong for x64,

Comment: building Google code on Windows is always a pain in the ass. if you have no specific reason *to build* skia rather than just wanting to use Skia, it is a lot easier to install Microsofts package manager vcpkg and set up Skia that way.

Comment: The 64-bit compiler and libraries are stored in VC\Tools\Llvm\x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out that for some reason (not sure what), Skia has a problem with the LLVM version installed using the Visual Studio Installer. I downloaded LLVM directly from their official website and then ran:

> bin/gn gen out/Shared --args='clang_win="C:\Program Files\LLVM" is_component_build=true is_debug=false is_official_build=true skia_use_system_expat=false skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_system_libwebp=false skia_use_system_zlib=false skia_use_system_icu=false skia_use_system_harfbuzz=false target_cpu="x64"'

Running this Skia builds without any errors.